# How can I eliminate nested require when combining two js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, uglifyjs

I`m trying to combine javascript files, I tried uglifyjs and it works but I want to eliminate duplicate require for the same npm library. 
Use case:
I have file1.js and file2.js. Both files are using for example request npm module, and when I combine these two files into one, it duplicates the require('request'). Is there an option or something I can eliminate this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to pass the module as parameter to another file.
For example:

file1.js

```
var request = require('request');
var file2 = require('./file2')(request);

module.exports = {...};
```

file2.js

```
module.exports = function(request) {

  // use "request" parameter, instead of requiring.   

  return {...};

};
```

Update:

```
import * as file2 from './file2';

const file2Module = file2(request);
```

Comment: this does not work when using typescript. when importing I can`t pass a variable

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: can you show me a sample? I tried i and tsc translated it:
this -> import rm = require('./src/ResponseMapper')(request)
to this -> var rm = require("./src/ResponseMapper");
(request);